# Ajax Function Syntax understanding

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to Ajax.I am bit confused looking at this below example.

```
$.ajax({              
    url: "test.html",               
    cache: false,           
    success: function(html){                  
        $("#results").append(html);
    }
});
```

Please help me to understand this function.How it is executed.
I can see that,the below  block code is passed as argument

```
{
    url: "test.html",              
    cache: false,               
    success: function(html){                
        $("#results").append(html);               
    }                    
}
```

this is passed as a argument to the function Ajax().

Answer (score 0):

The `success` callback is invoked when the AJAX call returns with no errors...

I think you should read jQuery [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation

Comment: Thanks for this link.

Comment: Your welcome... An upvote / accepting the answer is the right thing to do then :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's a typical way to call javascript functions, since Javascript does not have keyword arguments.

What happens is you pass an object (POJO) with parameters to your method then inside method you can access arguments and use them.

So in this way you can eliminate huge function arguments and also give client the ability pass whatever argument it's interested in.

So in `ajax` method the implementation code will read parameters that it needs and them executes the implementation logic. Of course if you need to know what parameters are exactly expected and accepted you should refer to JQuery `ajax` method call. (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

I hope this little info helps you to better understand how it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .its really help full